# What to put as 'Authorized Domain' under Firebase authentication for a single page Google App Script webapp

Tags: google-apps-script, firebase-authentication

In my Google App Script webapp, I would like to implement Firebase Phone authentication using FirebaseUI. But I am getting an error 'Hostname match not found' error when authenticating after reCaptcha verification.

So, please help me to understand:

1. If Firebase phone auth can be implemented for GAS webapps using FirebaseUI?
2. If yes, then what should I put as the 'Authorized Domain'? (I have tried with script.google.com, but it did not work)

Edit: After further studying, I found that the GAS webapp is served over a subdomain of script.googleusercontent.com and was able to use FirebaseUI phone auth by adding the subdomain as 'Authorized Domain' under Firebase auth.

Now, I would like to understand:

1. The subdomain over which a GAS webapp is served, is it exclusive and static per appscript project?